# Is there a rigorous mathematical definition of the Koch curve?

Tags: definition, fractals

Is there a rigorous mathematical definition of the Koch curve? Wikipedia says that mathematics is not given a rigorous formal definition of a fractal in general. And also I have not found a strict definition of the Koch curve. Everywhere write "go to the limit of the curves." But what is the formal definition of the limit of the curves?

Comment: "go to the limit of the curves." Seems pretty rigorous to me: the approximating curves $\gamma_n$ are such that, for every $t$, the sequence $(\gamma_n(t))$ converges when $n\to\infty$, call its limit $\gamma(t)$, and here you have the function $\gamma$ (which happens to be continuous, as it should be) defining the Koch curve.

Comment: While Did's comment is completely correct, it's worth noting that pointwise limits of functions (in this case, the sequence of functions $\gamma_n: \mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}^2$) don't necessarily preserve any properties such as continuity, so if you want to show that the limit here defines a _continuous_ curve then a little more care has to be taken.  Nevertheless, this can all be done relatively straightforwardly.

Comment: What formally means the limit of the curves? For example for limit of the function in the point I can write that $ (\forall \epsilon > 0) (\exists \delta>0)(\forall x \in D)(0 < |x-c|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \epsilon) $. Can I write something same for limit of the curves?

Comment: Note that vertices are fixed, and segment lengths are powers of 1/3. Now pick some small $\epsilon>0$. There is a step where all segment lengths are smaller than $\epsilon$.

Comment: @StanislavMorozov This is in my first comment: the limit means that $\gamma_n(t)\to\gamma(t)$ for every fixed $t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rigorous definition means that you have to use a consistent parameterization for each step in the construct. What we do to achieve this is to keep the first third and last third of each segment intact and replace the middle third. So in complex plane we start with the parameterization:

$$\gamma_0(t) = t$$

Then the step is done by replacing the middle segments. This is most easily done by adding a perpendicular offset. To do this we just put

$$\gamma_{n+1}(t) = \gamma_n(t) + i\gamma_n'(t)\phi(3^nt)3^{-n}$$

where the derivative is taken to be one sided (we will anyway have to rely on $\phi(3^nt)=0$ in the corner ponts of $\gamma$) and $\phi$ is a function for the perpendicular offset:

$$\phi(t) = \begin{cases} \sqrt{3}(t-n-1/3) & \mbox{if } n+1/3 \le t \le n+1/2 \\
-\sqrt{3}(t-n-2/3) & \mbox{if } n+1/2 < t \le n+2/3 \\
0 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Now we have a sequence of functions $\gamma_n$ and have to make some things certain as we are to define the Koch curve as $\gamma(t) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\gamma_n(t)$.

First of all we have to show that $\gamma_n(t)$ is continuous which should be rather straight forward. We use that $\gamma_n'(t)$ is continuous (actually constant) whenever $\phi(3^nt)\ne0$.

We also should prove that $|\gamma_{n+1}(t)-\gamma_n(t)|<(2/3)^n$ which would guarantee that $\gamma(t) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\gamma_n(t)$ is defined at all, but also that it converges uniformly and therefore $\gamma(t)$ is continuous as well.

$$\gamma_{n+1}(t)-\gamma_n(t) = i\gamma_n'(t)\phi(3^nt)3^{-n}$$

in order to estimate this we need an estimate of the derivative:

$$|\gamma_{n+1}'(t)|= |\gamma_n'(t) + i\gamma_n''(t)\phi(3^nt)3^{-n} + i\gamma_n'(t)\phi'(3^nt)| = |\gamma_n'(t) (1 + i\phi'(3^nt))| < 2|\gamma_n'(t)|$$

This means that $|\gamma_n'(t)|<2^n$ inserting it

$$|\gamma_{n+1}(t)-\gamma_n(t)| = |i\gamma_n'(t)\phi(3^nt)3^{-n}| < 2^n|\phi(3^nt)|3^{-n} < (2/3)^n$$